# JS group nested array by date field

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have such an array structure:

```
[
  {
    group: "perf",
    subgroups: [
      {
        date: "2020-08-20",
        number: 2
      },
      {
        date: "2020-08-21",
        number: 3
      }
    ],
    number: 5
  },
  {
    group: "mobile",
    subgroups: [
      {
        date: "2020-08-20",
        number: 4
      },
      {
        date: "2020-08-21",
        number: 6
      }
    ],
    number: 10
  },
  {
    group: "games",
    subgroups: [
      {
        date: "2020-08-20",
        number: 7
      },
      {
        date: "2020-08-21",
        number: 8
      },
        {
        date: "2020-08-22",
        number: 1
      }
    ],
    number: 16
  },
  {
    group: "levels",
    subgroups: [
      {
        date: "2020-08-09",
        number: 4
      },
      {
        date: "2020-08-20",
        number: 9
      },
      {
        date: "2020-08-21",
        number: 11
      }
    ],
    number: 24
  }
]
```

I need to create a mapper over this array to receive such output:

`total` - the overall sum of numbers for the specific date.

```
[
    {
      date: "2020-08-09",
      total: 4,
      levels: 4
    },
    {
      date: "2020-08-20",
      total: 22,
      perf: 2,
      mobile: 4,
      games: 7,
      levels: 9,
    },
    {
      date: "2020-08-21",
      total: 28,
      perf: 3,
      mobile: 6,
      games: 8,
      levels: 11,
    },
    {
      date: "2020-08-22",
      total: 1,
      games: 1
    }
]
```

How can this be achieved? I was trying, using `reduce` but cannot figure out, how to group it by dates.

Here's what I've tried so far:
https://jsfiddle.net/wqhj62od/

Or maybe it can be done easily using lodash?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with plain JS, require some manipulation here

- group total value of each type by date
- map through the group and calculate the total of all values

```
const dateValueLookup = arr.reduce((acc, el) => {
  el.subgroups.forEach((subgroup) => {
    if (!acc[subgroup.date]) {
      acc[subgroup.date] = {}
    }
    if (!acc[subgroup.date][el.group]) {
      acc[subgroup.date][el.group] = 0
    }
    acc[subgroup.date][el.group] += subgroup.number
  })
  return acc
}, {})

const res = Object.entries(dateValueLookup)
  .sort(([keyA], [keyB]) => keyA.localeCompare(keyB))
  .map(([date, values]) => ({
    date,
    total: Object.values(values).reduce((sum, value) => sum + value, 0),
    ...values,
  }))
```

```js
const arr = [
  {
    group: "perf",
    subgroups: [
      {
        date: "2020-08-20",
        number: 2,
      },
      {
        date: "2020-08-21",
        number: 3,
      },
    ],
    number: 5,
  },
  {
    group: "mobile",
    subgroups: [
      {
        date: "2020-08-20",
        number: 4,
      },
      {
        date: "2020-08-21",
        number: 6,
      },
    ],
    number: 10,
  },
  {
    group: "games",
    subgroups: [
      {
        date: "2020-08-20",
        number: 7,
      },
      {
        date: "2020-08-21",
        number: 8,
      },
      {
        date: "2020-08-22",
        number: 1,
      },
    ],
    number: 16,
  },
  {
    group: "levels",
    subgroups: [
      {
        date: "2020-08-09",
        number: 4,
      },
      {
        date: "2020-08-20",
        number: 9,
      },
      {
        date: "2020-08-21",
        number: 11,
      },
    ],
    number: 24,
  },
]

const dateValueLookup = arr.reduce((acc, el) => {
  el.subgroups.forEach((subgroup) => {
    if (!acc[subgroup.date]) {
      acc[subgroup.date] = {}
    }
    if (!acc[subgroup.date][el.group]) {
      acc[subgroup.date][el.group] = 0
    }
    acc[subgroup.date][el.group] += subgroup.number
  })
  return acc
}, {})

const res = Object.entries(dateValueLookup)
  .sort(([keyA], [keyB]) => keyA.localeCompare(keyB))
  .map(([date, values]) => ({
    date,
    total: Object.values(values).reduce((sum, value) => sum + value, 0),
    ...values,
  }))

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a Map keyed by date, with the final objects as values. Then iterate the data and update those objects. Finally extract the values from the Map and sort them:

```js
function ungroup(data) {
    let map = new Map(data.flatMap(({subgroups}) => 
        subgroups.map(({date}) => [date, { date, total: 0 }])
    ));
    for (let {group, subgroups} of data) {
        for (let {date, number} of subgroups) {
            let obj = map.get(date);
            obj.total += obj[group] = number;
        }
    }
    return Array.from(map.values()).sort((a, b) => a.date.localeCompare(b.date));
}

let data = [{group: "perf",subgroups: [{date: "2020-08-20",number: 2},{date: "2020-08-21",number: 3}],number: 5},{group: "mobile",subgroups: [{date: "2020-08-20",number: 4},{date: "2020-08-21",number: 6}],number: 10},{group: "games",subgroups: [{date: "2020-08-20",number: 7},{date: "2020-08-21",number: 8},{date: "2020-08-22",number: 1}],number: 16},{group: "levels",subgroups: [{date: "2020-08-09",number: 4},{date: "2020-08-20",number: 9},{date: "2020-08-21",number: 11}],number: 24}];
let result = ungroup(data);
console.log(result);
```